# When using atop as a systemd service it only runs and logs to file once

Tags: centos, systemd, top, cpu-usage, atop

I am on **CentOS 7** and using **atop v2.6.0**

If I run atop manually with the following command everything runs as expected and the log is written to every 10 seconds:

`/usr/bin/atop -w /var/log/atop/atop_20210320 10`

However when running atop as a service with systemd the log is only written to once when the service starts and never updated.

I can confirm via `ps -ef` that the service has initiated the command and it's running:

`root      2320     1  0 13:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop  -w /var/log/atop/atop_20210320 10`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.